# What is the functional difference between creating a Java frame inside the main class and creating a Java Frame inside a constructor?

Tags: java, swing, frame

If I create a frame inside the 'main()', then only one instance of the frame would be created.

If I create a frame inside a constructor, then each time the class is instantiated, a new frame would be created.

Could someone give me some real-time scenarios where the above two methods would be used?

Comment: It is not something that can be answered in one or two sentence, you need firstly learn the basics of Java language, then such kind of question can be answered by your self. Good Luck!

Comment: If this is not a duplicate, please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your chosen approach.

Comment: The second generates a side effect which may not always be desirable, constructors should be focused on setting up the state of the object

Comment: @MadProgrammer ..another undesirable side effect of creating a frame in the constructor is that it locks the class into appearing in a frame! It might also be needed to display the component (a panel, presumably) in a window, a dialog, a tab of a tabbed pane, a split pane, one part of the layout of another panel .. The 'frame in constructor' presumably also sets the component visible at the same time, but that might not be the desired result.

Comment: @trashgod Thanks for your guidance. Next time I'll frame my question properly.

Comment: @MadProgrammer and Andrew Thompson: Thanks for your inputs, which answered my question partly.